# freeze assets in wallet

Tags: solidity, assets

I want to freeze my assets in my wallet, for example I want to freeze 1 ETH in my wallet for up to 1 week.

Is it possible to achieve this with solidity? how?

Answer (score 0):

Not in a traditional wallet, unless the wallet supports such functionality. Traditional wallets are just regular software, and do not utilize Solidity or other blockchain code - they just connect to the blockchain.

But nothing stops you from writing a contract which freezes assets you send to it. Basically you need to compare timestamps and allow withdrawal of the assets after certain amount of time has passed from the deposit.